# UINavigationController background color while flipping views

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller

Okay, so here it goes. I have a project with a fairly complex interface, including a hierarchical navigator on which when I select a leaf item, I'm presenting either one of two content controllers (because the user can view products which are of two kinds that need their own controller). Think of it as a folder navigator, where folder are nested, and there are only two kind of files, each having its own viewer. When I select a file, I present a modal controller, either a "docAViewController", either a "docBViewController".

That's working perfectly.

My problem is: the docBViewController is a UINavigationController that flips between two UIViewControllers. (I've inherited that from another developer's architecture and have to cope with it).

When I flip the two view controllers (a viewer and an info pane), the background color is white when I want it to be black. The docBViewController is created by code (no XIB), and I've tried setting its background color by `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]` in its `viewDidLoad` method, it does nothing.

Anyone knows where/how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you flipping the views?  There are a few ways to do it.

I've noticed that when using UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion that both the view being flipped and the view replacing it must share a parent view of the same size for the animation to work correctly.  More to your question, this parent view's background does not appear (if the background is black, you might still see white while the other views flip), but its parent's background will.

So...

The view you are flipping needs 1.) a parent that will define the area being flipped and 2.) a parent of its parent for a background that doesn't move during the animation.

This is what I've observed.

Comment: Maybe the dev who created that should've used `presentModalViewController` with a transitionStyle set to flip, but he did it by manually declaring a UIView animation and flipping the two viewcontrollers' viewws "by hand". I'll try to see what I can achieve with the parent's background...

Comment: Solved it by setting `[window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackcolor]]` in the app delegate's `didFinishLaunching`. Thanks!

Comment: @Cyrille - exactly what I've been trying to do for the past hour! Awesome!

Comment: @Cyrille much appreciated, thank you. anyway to make the background a custom VC or image?